# Angular 2 ngOnDestroy is not triggering

Tags: angular, routes, loader, ondestroy

Good morning fellows

I've developed a small angular2-client-app which got routes. The routes are created like this:

> app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact.component/contact.component';
import { Home } from './components/home.component/home.component';
import {StudentRoutes} from './components/student.component/student.routes';
import {LecturerRoutes} from "./components/lecturer.component/lecturer.routes";
import {ProcessRoutes} from "./components/process.component/process.routes";
import {SchoolRoutes} from "./components/school.component/school.routes";

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: Home },
    ...ProcessRoutes,
    ...StudentRoutes,
    ...LecturerRoutes,
    ...SchoolRoutes,
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

So now my clients can route around from component to component.

All my components are extending one parent-component: base-component.ts

> base-component.ts

```
import { Component, Injectable, Inject, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { NavigationService } from '../services/navigation-service';
// import {Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ComponentService } from '../services/component-service';
import { MenuItem } from '../models/menu-item';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {Broadcaster} from "../services/broadcaster";
import {ScreenSize} from "../models/screen-size";
import {LoaderService} from "../services/loader-service";

@Component({
    selector: 'base-component',
    template: ""
})

@Injectable()
export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    constructor(componentService: ComponentService, 
    protected navigationService: NavigationService, 
    broadcaster: Broadcaster,
    protected loaderSrv:LoaderService, 
    screen:ScreenSize = ScreenSize.TwoColumns) {
        let items = new Array<MenuItem>();
        let parent = componentService.GetParentPath(location.pathname);
        this.navigationService.GetSideNavigation(parent).subscribe((x) => {
            items = x.map(y => new MenuItem(y.name, y.url, y.children))
            broadcaster.broadcast("sideNavigation", items[0].children);
        });
        broadcaster.broadcast("screenSize", screen);
    }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.loaderSrv.start();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loaderSrv.stop(); 
  }
}
```

Every time the user changes the route, he should first hit the **ngOnDestroy** Method, because my object gets cleared out. and after, it should hit the **ngOnInit** Method, because we just created a new object by routing to it.

The problem:
It never triggers the **ngOnDestroy** Method... He does trigger the ngOnInit-Method, but never ngOnDestroy...

Here is a snippet out of my package.json so you can check my angular2 versions:

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3"
```

Would be great if somebody could give me a good tip.

Peace out!

Comment: Destroy on same page at bottom because when its navigate from one page to another Its check on that page is anything available to destry while navigating

Comment: If I got your comment right, you want me to put the 2 methods in every single component? I testet also that, it's also not working. ngOnDestroy is not triggering even in the component self. If I don't got you right, please leave another comment!

Comment: check i have given plnkr eample for more details https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnDestroy-class.html

Answer (score 5):

Finally got it...

The error was in the HTML.

I used the element *a* with *href* to route through the sites. That was false! The **right way** is to use **Routerlink**

**<del>`<a href="/site">Site</a>`</del>**

**`<a [RouterLink]="['/site']">Site</a>`**

Than all live cycle hooks will work again!